# unknown number of columns into one

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame contains unknown number of columns like below.

```
  Start               End           0          1        2      3      4     5      6 ...
 7/5/2021 22:04    7/6/2021 6:26    E1234    H5511     T3333  H2222 
 7/5/2021 16:35    7/5/2021 16:35   T3456    (Tafresh)              
 7/5/2021 19:44                     T6789    E1111
```

I need to convert all columns except "Start" and "End" columns into one column

the result is as

```
  Start               End           0    
 7/5/2021 22:04    7/6/2021 6:26    E1234
 7/5/2021 22:04    7/6/2021 6:26    H5511
 7/5/2021 22:04    7/6/2021 6:26    T3333
 7/5/2021 22:04    7/6/2021 6:26    H2222
 7/5/2021 16:35    7/5/2021 16:35   T3456
 7/5/2021 16:35    7/5/2021 16:35   (Tafresh)           
 7/5/2021 19:44                     T6789      
 7/5/2021 19:44                     E1111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
new_df = df.set_index(['Start', 'End']).stack().droplevel(2).reset_index()
```

`stack` is preferred here over `melt` since it will drop `nan` values and the order will be correct relative to expected output.

`new_df`

```
            Start             End          0
0  7/5/2021 22:04   7/6/2021 6:26      E1234
1  7/5/2021 22:04   7/6/2021 6:26      H5511
2  7/5/2021 22:04   7/6/2021 6:26      T3333
3  7/5/2021 22:04   7/6/2021 6:26      H2222
4  7/5/2021 16:35  7/5/2021 16:35      T3456
5  7/5/2021 16:35  7/5/2021 16:35  (Tafresh)
6  7/5/2021 19:44             NaN      T6789
7  7/5/2021 19:44             NaN      E1111
```

---

DataFrame used:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Start': ['7/5/2021 22:04', '7/5/2021 16:35', '7/5/2021 19:44'],
    'End': ['7/6/2021 6:26', '7/5/2021 16:35', nan],
    '0': ['E1234', 'T3456', 'T6789'],
    '1': ['H5511', '(Tafresh)', 'E1111'],
    '2': ['T3333', nan, nan],
    '3': ['H2222', nan, nan]
})
```